# Automatically fold uninteresting elements - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.6

There is an option is eclipse for `Automatically fold uninteresting elements`. Can anyone explain what does this actually does? Tried googling, but didn't get any valid explanation or answers.

Found below answer:

```
Should fold comments other than javadoc comments.
```

But nothing is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, this is part of Mylin (http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/), a task-focused interface.